# Sql spatial data query not returning points in polygon

Tags: sql, azure, polygon, spatial, point

I have a sql table called "Person" with a column called "GeoLocation" and a data type of geography.  I have inserted a row into the table like so:

```
insert into person (Name, GeoLocation)
values ('Point A', geography::Point(32.7466, -96.4489, 4326))
```

This inserts a point with latitude of 32.7466 and longitude of -96.4489.
I then run a query to find if the point intersects with a polygon.

```
declare @shape geography 

set @shape = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-170 35, -170 30, -30 30, -30 35, -170 35))', 4326)

select * from Person
where GeoLocation.STIntersects(@shape) = 1
```

In the code above I am specifying longitude, then latitude for each coordinate in a counter clockwise order starting at the top/left point.

The point should be within the polygon but it returns as false.

If I change the query as below it works and returns true.

```
declare @shape geography 

set @shape = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-100 35, -100 30, -90 30, -90 35, -100 35))', 4326)

select * from Person
where GeoLocation.STIntersects(@shape) = 1
```

I'm not sure why that would be.  Is there a setting in Azure SQL that restricts the maximum polygon size.  I'm specifying a rectangle but only changing its width. I'm not sure why the point is no longer found within its boundary.

I was expecting the point to be within both polygons.  I have tried using other methods such as STWithin but get the same result.

Comment: I believe this has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195814/spatial-query-in-sql-not-correctly-returning-intersection-on-area-and-point